# Is it possible to re-import a Trello board?

Tags: trello, import, trello-boards

After exporting a Trello board as JSON or CSV,
is it possible to import it again? (to the same/new account)

Answer (score 2):

1. If you exported the JSON with the intention of re-importing the board elsewhere, you should [transfer the board](https://trello.com/support/transfer-boards) instead.
2. If you want to copy the board to a new team:

   - Copy the board you want in the origin team (Menu > More... > Copy Board)
   - Transfer the board copy to the destination team
3. If you exported a JSON and you don't have access anymore to the original board, then you should follow boardtc's advice.

Comment: Link to boardtc's advice?

Comment: Uh, I'm afraid the comment was deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Trello offers export options for JSON and CSV export from the menu on the right of the board

[image: Export menu in Trello]

You can then import using the (free) [import power-up](https://trello.com/power-ups/61fa6cd2cc14647c2c9ee821/import-to-trello-by-blue-cat-csv-excel). If you have exported as JSON you will need to convert that to CSV for the importer, but that is easy enough to do with a service like [JSON to CSV](https://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm)